# How can I change the default browser?

Tags: browser, default-applications

I need to change the default browser in my Android device to Opera. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: That being said: If you installed Opera and open *any* link, it should ask you which browser to choose.

Comment: Voted to close since this question is actually about how to code an app to open a link with the default browser.

Comment: Ugh. If that's the case then [the original question on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871147/changing-the-default-browser-in-android-device?noredirect=1) should be re-opened after more and better detail is added.

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14231/how-can-i-get-a-overview-and-manage-the-default-applications-for-file-types

Answer (score 42):

After installing Opera, when you open a link from somewhere in the system, you should see a popup asking you to choose between the browsers available. That popup should have a checkbox for saving the browser you choose as the default browser.

If you have already set a default browser, you must go to **Settings** > **Applications** > **Manage applications**, find the browser you now have as default and click on "**Clear defaults**" in the details page, then go through the process described in the first paragraph.

Answer (score 15):

Certainly! Go in your **Settings**, **Manage Applications**. Click the **All** tab, and then select **Browser**. You must then click the **Clear Defaults** button.

Now next time that an application requires a browser (say, you click a link in your Twitter app) the **Complete action using** dialog will pop up and you can select Opera and tick the **Use by default for this action** box.

**Followup**: Make sure that you have installed Opera (or any other browser of your choice). If you only have the default browser installed, you will not get the **Complete action using** dialog. Again, look in  **Settings**, **Manage Applications** but this time go in **Downloaded** to make sure that your preferred browser is there.

Comment: I already do this but no result

Comment: I want to open a link in opera Through an app

Comment: @surendra Are you developing the app?

Comment: yes i that i have to open an url in opera browser

Comment: @surendra: if you're not getting the dialog when opening a link from your app, there must be something wrong in the way you're doing it (programmatically). In that case you'd better ask your question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: while i am trying to open url through my app its opening in android default browser

Answer (score 5):

I'm using Android 2.3 and I couldn't find the stock browser to clear defaults. Then I realized that it is now called "Web" instead of "Browser" under `Settings - Applications - Manage applications - "All" tab`.

Answer (score 4):

Just as an update, an easier way (on Android 4.0+ ICS) would be to go:

Settings > Apps > App Associations, then tap on "Web URLs" and a box will come up showing all browsers installed, you tap on the one you want to be the default browser. Same way for e-mail address links, phone numbers, etc.

Comment: What phone do you have? This isn't an AOSP feature.

Comment: +1 I have a htc incredible 2, tried everything, your solution worked!

Answer (score 3):

If you're getting an option to choose which browser to use, select the checkbox to set the default and then tap Opera.

If you're not getting an option to choose a browser to use, then you need to go into your settings and clear the default from the current from the current browser: `Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications -> All -> [Current Default Browser] -> Clear Defaults`.  The next time you open a link from outside a browser, you'll be given the option to set the default.

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by @Bushibytes was actually more helpful to me, since I have a Samsung device.

The default browser is called "Internet". I think this was the case on my HTC with Orange (yep, just confirmed that).

I needed to click on "All" as @Bushibytes recommended, and then only can you see all the stock apps.

Answer (score 1):

For **Android M**:

`Settings`->`Apps`->`Advanced`->`Default App Settings`

All the default settings can be overridden there.

Answer (score 1):

Xiaomi MIUI - Settings -> App Settings > System Apps / Installed apps -> Defaults (bottom) -> Browser -> change your default browser.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion [Dafault App Manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.appiator.defaultappmanager) is the easiest way to configure the default apps (incl. the browser).

Answer (score 0):

Download Opera to your device.

When you try to open something which requires a browser, you will be given the chance to select a browser. Select Opera, and press the `Always` button.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the default app that is opening on your android now in settings > apps and click on it, then click disable, the next time you try to open the default browser you will be prompted to choose a default browser, and that's how it's done!

Comment: This is an option on 4.x and later. But some devices, like samsung devices, do not let you disable things like browser, email, calendar apps.

Answer (score 0):

For kitkat users

1. Open **Settings**
2. Go to **Apps**
3. On the **All tabs**, look for your default browser and tap on it
4. Under **Launch by Default**, press the "**Clear defaults**" button, to reset default browser
5. Then open a link, you are asked to select a browser, select Opera , select Always.

Comment: Your answer doesn't add anything useful as an answer to the question. Most of the answers already covered this step. What's the logic in adding redundancy?