# How can I change the default browser on MIUI 10.x?

Tags: browser, default-applications, miui, miui-10

I've read this question:

[How can I change the default browser?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11875/how-can-i-change-the-default-browser)

but the instructions there don't fit my Xiaomi phone, which has the MIUI 10 interface. How can I change the default browser there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In your Settings application, navigate to <kbd>System Applications</kbd> <kbd>Browser</kbd>.
2. You get a prompt saying:

   > **Set as default browser?**
   >
   > MIUI Browser is really great blah blah blah
   >   blah blah blah blah blah blah.
   >
   > No Thanks | Set
3. Tap "No Thanks".
4. Make sure "Set as default browser" is in the off position (grayed dot, not blue dot).
5. Open some application with web links.
6. Click a web link.
7. You will now get the dialog for choosing the app with which to open the link.
8. Tap "Remember my choice" or some equivalent wording before choosing your new default browser.